# How to check if a property placeholder exists in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

How to check if a property placeholder exists in Apache Camel?

I tried:

```
.choice()
    .when(simple("{{app.custom.property}}").isNotNull())
       ...
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property with key [app.custom.property] not found in properties from text: {{app.custom.property}}

I also tried ([note the ? (question mark) at the beginning of the key name](https://camel.apache.org/manual/using-propertyplaceholder.html#_using_optional_property_placeholders)):

```
.choice()
    .when(simple("{{?app.custom.property}}").isNotNull())
        ...
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Also ([with default value](https://camel.apache.org/manual/using-propertyplaceholder.html#_using_property_placeholder_with_default_value)):

```
.choice()
    .when(simple("{{app.custom.property:null}}").isNotNull())
        ...
```

> It is never `null` because (if not exists) it initializes the variable with the string `"null"`. I could compare against this string, but then I have no way of knowing if the property didn't really exist or if it had set that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Simple Language property lookup:

| Variable | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| properties:key:default | String | Camel 2.14.1: Lookup a property with the given key. If the key does not exists or has no value, then an optional default value can be specified. |

In your case, it would be: `${properties:app.custom.property:null}`

Answer (score 0):

I think , its is easiest and clean solution .  if you want use other properties  in other routes  u can write basic method for controlling property exist

```
public class Greeting  extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       
        boolean isExist = getCamelContext().getPropertiesComponent().resolveProperty("app.custom.property").isPresent();

     from("timer:hello")
        .choice()
        .when(constant(isExist)).log("exist")
        .otherwise().log("not exist");
        
    }

}
```